# How to stop a loop by using a word such as "exit" in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, exit

So I have a coding assignment to complete, and I am having trouble finishing it. The exact instructions are as follows:

> To make telephone numbers easier to remember, some companies use letters to show their telephone number.
> For example, using letters, the telephone number 438-5626 can be shown as GET LOAN. In some cases, to make a telephone number meaningful, companies might use more than seven letters. For example, 225-5466 can be displayed as CALL HOME, which uses eight letters.
>
> Write a program that does the following:
>
> - Prompts a user to enter Y or y to begin conversion, or any other input to quit.
> - Prompts the user to enter a telephone number expressed in letters and outputs the corresponding telephone number in digits
> - Processes only the first seven letters if the user enters more than seven letters.
> - Outputs the – (hyphen) after the third digit.
> - Allows the user to use both uppercase and lowercase letters as well as spaces between words.
> - Process as many telephone numbers as the user wants while allowing them to quit after each conversion.

I have currently completed all of the steps except for the last one (kind of).

The instructor is looking for the word "exit" to quit the program. Currently, I have it set up for "%" to end the program. Logically you would say to just change the "%" to "exit" and move on, but I get an error when I do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{        
    int counter;        
    char phoneNumber;
    char cont;
    
    //  Prompts a user to enter Y or y to begin conversion, or any other input to quit. 
    cout << "Please enter 'Y' or 'y' to continue, otherwise the program with quit.\n Input: ";
    cin >> cont;
    if (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y')
    {            
        // statement(s) will execute if the boolean expression is true
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
        // statement(s) will execute if the boolean expression is false
    }
    
    cout << "To stop this program enter 'exit'." << endl;
    cout << "Enter a phone number in letters only \nNOTE: Must enter 7 or more letters: ";
    cin >> phoneNumber;
    cout << endl;
    phoneNumber = static_cast<char>(toupper(phoneNumber));
    while (phoneNumber != '%')
    {
        cout << "\nTo stop this program enter 'exit'." << endl;
        cout << "Enter a phone number in letters only." << endl;
        
        for (counter = 0; phoneNumber != '%' && counter < 7; counter++)
        {
            cin >> phoneNumber;
            
            if (counter == 3)
                cout << "-";
            
            if ((phoneNumber >= 'A' && phoneNumber <= 'Z') || 
                (phoneNumber >= 'a' && phoneNumber <= 'z'))
                switch (phoneNumber)
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'b':
                    case 'C':
                    case 'c':
                        cout << 2;
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                    case 'd':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'F':
                    case 'f':
                        cout << 3;
                        break;
                    case 'G':
                    case 'g':
                    case 'H':
                    case 'h':
                    case 'I':
                    case 'i':
                        cout << 4;
                        break;
                        
                    case 'J':
                    case 'j':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'k':
                    case 'L':
                    case 'l':
                        cout << 5;
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                    case 'm':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'n':
                    case 'O':
                    case 'o':
                        cout << 6;
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                    case 'p':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'r':
                    case 'S':
                    case 's':
                        cout << 7;
                        break;
                        
                    case 'T':
                    case 't':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'u':
                    case 'V':
                    case 'v':
                        cout << 8;
                        break;
                        
                    case 'W':
                    case 'w':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'x':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'y':
                    case 'Z':
                    case 'z':
                        cout << 9;
                        break;
                }
        }
        while (cin.get() != '\n')
            ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think it has something to do with the char, and that's all I could find out. I have been searching the internet for an answer, but I came up empty. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of that really gnarly `switch` statement consider using a simple lookup table.

Comment: You could also switch from using interactive input to taking command-line arguments. `argv` on `main` gives you simple strings. Iterate over that list and call your number function. Remember single quotes delimit *single characters*, so `'exit'` is not going to work. You'll need to keep state and track the sequence `e`,`x`, `i`, `t`, which is really a lot of work when you can end with a single character instead. This is also a bad plan because 1-888-333-EXIT is a valid phone number by your definition. The C convention is to wait for a newline character, or ASCII 10.

Comment: When asking questions, instead of saying "I get an error", provide more details by giving us the exact error message.

Comment: the `tolower` function will hack the number `switch` `case`s down by half.

Comment: @all thanks so much for your comments. @tadman, that is a great idea, but at this point, I already have the `switch` statement, so I'm just going to keep it. In the future, I will shorten it. You have also given me great advice with your second comment. I have gotten some other help since this post (down in the answers). Thanks for your help though. @Wyck, I apologize for not stating my error. I am new to this website, and am still getting a hang of it. Sorry.  @user4581301 great advice, but as I said earlier, I already have the statements there, and Im just going to leave them at this point.

Comment: Also see [How do I break from a loop if a user enters a certain word into a structure? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9769901/608639)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the phonenumber variable to "exit" it needs to be a string, not a char.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is a big difference between a char and a string. A char is a single character while a string is a bunch of characters. For strings, a bunch can mean 0, 1 or more characters. The twos are differentiated by the use of apostrophe (for char) or quotation marks (for string). Since your program only uses char as input, when you get an input longer than one character, your program doesn't know how to handle this. You will have to make use of strings to include the case where you have to write "exit".

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure of your program should be:

```
int main() {
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && line != "exit") {
        std::cout << phone_digits(line) << "\n";
    }
}
```

That's almost as simple as it gets. The "exit" condition is not strictly necessary since there is a widespread convention about how to signal the end of the input. On Windows, it's Ctrl+Z, while on UNIX-like systems (Linux, NetBSD, macOS) it's Ctrl+D.

I also don't understand why you first have enter 'y' to actually start the program. That's unnecessary too, but your teacher will probably insist on that nevertheless.

The next thing is to write the `phone_digits` function and place it *above* the main function. This function takes a string as the argument and also returns a string.

```
std::string phone_digits(const std::string &input) {
    std::string result;

    // TODO: convert letters from input to digits in output
    // TODO: insert the hyphen in the result

    return result;
}
```

To write the function in this form, you have to read the documentation of the `std::string` class, to find out how to loop over all characters from the input and how to add characters to the end of the result string.

Comment: If the keystrokes to signal end of input are different between windows and unix,  it can hardly be described as a "widespread convention".    A widespread convention applies in the same way, whenever it is used.    And, BTW, in windows - depending on context - it can be necessary to enter CTRL-Z twice, or to enter a newline followed by CTRL-Z.    Entering CTRL-Z under unix typically suspends the process, it doesn't signal end of input.

Comment: @Peter At the beginning of a line, a single Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+D is enough, and that is exactly the input pattern expected here. A widespread convention does not need to be the same everywhere. For example, instead of Ctrl+D I typically type Strg+D because I'm using a German keyboard. Nevertheless this convention can be called widespread.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Roland, I attempted to add what you suggested to the code I had, and I got the following error--
  main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
  main.cpp:40:20: error: ‘in’ was not declared in this scope
       while (getline(in, line) && line != "exit") {
                             ^~
  main.cpp:40:20: note: suggested alternative: ‘int’
       while (getline(in, line) && line != "exit") {
                             ^~
                              int
  bash: line 2: ./a.out: No such file or directory--
I'm sorry, but I'm quite new to the language. Thanks again!

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. Instead of `std::in` I wanted to write `std::cin`. Maybe I thought of the C programming language (where this variable is called `stdin`), or I just forgot the `c`.

Comment: Running the code now seems to work until you enter the phrase to convert to a phone number.  It just doesn't output any value. Attempting to run the code in Visual Studio shows an error with `getline`.  This is the exact code at that part, `phoneNumber = static_cast<char>(toupper(phoneNumber));
 while (getline(cin, line) && line != "exit") {
  cout << phone_digits(line);
 }`
Visual studio is saying that `getline` is not defined, but doing my reseach says that `getline` is not a variable, but rather a function such as `while` or `cin`.

Thanks for your help again!

Comment: To solve this, google "c++ getline". This will lead you to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/. In the upper right corner that page says `<string>`, which means "to use this function, you need to `#include <string>` at the top of the file". You have some other misconceptions. `while` is not a function, although the code continues with `(` afterwards. Instead it is a built-in control structure. Neither is `cin` a function since it isn't followed by `(`. (That's a bit imprecise but sufficient for the moment.)

Comment: Okay so I have now gotten to the point where the code executes. The only issue now is that after I enter "y" to continue, it wont convert any word into numbers. Only after I enter "exit" does it continue. "Exit" is supposed to end the function, but instead it is a barrier preventing the code from continuing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without seeing your actual code — no chance. Except that you may have typed `==` instead of `!=` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help me. I really appreciate it. Here is the code for that section. I dont see any `==` instead of `!=`. 

`cout << "To stop this program enter 'exit'." << endl;
 cout << "Enter a phone number in letters only \nNOTE: Must enter 7 or more letters: ";
 cin >> phoneNumber;
 cout << endl;
 phoneNumber = static_cast<char>(toupper(phoneNumber));
 while (getline(cin, line) && line != "exit") {
  cout << phone_digits(line);
 }
 while (phoneNumber != '%')`

Comment: A phone number is not a single character. It _consists_ of many characters. Therefore it is wrong to try `static_cast<char>` or `toupper` on it. As a beginner, don't use `static_cast` at all. All programs that you write at this stage must work without using this feature. By the way, you don't need the `phoneNumber` variable at all since the `line` already contains the phone number.