# Is there a way to stop an ongoing loop by typing something in C++?

Tags: c++, loops

I was wondering if there is a way to stop an ongoing loop in C++ by writing something while the code is being executed.

For example, if I have an infinite loop in my program that types the letter "A" every second. I want to be able to write "finish" to act like a sudden "break" function whenever I want in the middle of executing the program.

Comment: Well Ctrl+C on unix will do. But it will just kill the program. I'm noto sure if that's what you needed

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please show your loop with some comments indicating what you want to do and where you want to do it. Maybe something like [How to stop a loop by using a word such as "exit" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54877579/608639)

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about multi-threaded programming.  Your request is basically the same principle as (in the GUI world) having to check for a "stop" button being pressed to stop a long-running task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah you can do that. how about this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

void wait() {
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        if (line.compare("stop!!") == 0) {
            std::cout << "stopping\n";
            exit(0);
        }

    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread wait_for_your_command (wait);
    while (1) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "foo\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!
Should just mention I had to add #include <cstdlib> for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

One is multi-threading, just like @marcelo827 said.

The other is that you can use the `get-char` function with NON-BLOCKING.

```
string str;
while (true)
{
    char ch = get_char_non_blocking();
    str += ch;
    if (str == "whatever")
    {
        break;
    }
    // print A per second        
}
```

However, C/C++ Standard library doesn't provide us the function `get_char_non_blocking()`.

`getch()` is what you need, this function works on Windows(`#include <conio.h>`) and on Linux(`#include <ncurses.h>`, ofc you may need install the library ncurses by yourself).

BTW, multi-threading shouldn't be your first choice unless you have no other choice or unless you know exactly what you are doing. Because multi-threading has a price.